# Transmitting from leapmotion to arduino returns error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1

Tags: java, arduino, processing

I'm transmitting data from Leap-Motion to Arduino through processing. However, it always returns error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1"

Here's the code that's generating the error but I just don't know what's causing the issue.

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;
import com.onformative.leap.LeapMotionP5;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Hand;

LeapMotionP5 leap;
float xhand;
float yhand;
float zhand;

void setup(){
  frameRate(20);
  size(500, 500, P2D);

  myPort = new Serial(this, "COM7", 57600);
  myPort.bufferUntil ('\n');
  leap = new LeapMotionP5(this);
}

void draw(){
background(23,23,200);
ellipse(getHandX()+30, getHandZ()+320, 55, 55);

line( 200, 500, 200, 0);
line( 300, 500, 300, 0);
line( 0, 200, 500, 200);
line( 0, 300, 500, 300);

int handCt = 0;

 for (Hand hand : leap.getHandList()) {
     if (handCt == 0) {
      PVector handPos = leap.getPosition(hand);
      setHandPos( handPos.x, handPos.y, handPos.z );
     }
     handCt++;

    int throttle = (int)map(getHandY(), height-100, -100, 0, 85);
    throttle = constrain(throttle, 0, 85);
    int pitch = (int)map(getHandZ(), -500, 1000, 171, 250);
    pitch = constrain(pitch, 171, 250);
    int yaw= (int)map(getHandX(), width-130, -width, 86, 170);
    yaw = constrain(yaw, 86, 170);
    myPort.write(yaw);
    myPort.write(pitch);
    myPort.write(throttle);
    println(pitch);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **Please provide the full stack trace.**

Comment: give your complete logcat.

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown when you're trying to reference an array element which doesn't exist. That means the specified index is greater or equal to the length of the array, as the first element in an array has an index of 0 (not 1).

I'd expect it is occurring in this this line:

```
String portName = Serial.list()[1];
```

It must be that the array it is trying to access only has one element, which is found at index 0.

Comment: Hi benjamin and Arkanon, thanks for replying. I've tried changing the array to index 0 as advised, however, the same error repeats itself just that the error message becomes java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0.

Please advise,
Many Thanks,
Joshua Lay

Comment: Can you maybe post your full code so we can have a better look for the source of the issue?

Comment: Hi I managed to get the programme to work however another the error came out as which is NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: Hi I managed to get rid of that problem by deleting that line and make the changes as shown above however a new error popped up it shows a NoSuchMethodError.

Answer (score 0):

Dosn't the error give you a specific line where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, i've solved my problem. I realized that the code above is to be used for a MAC and not for a windows computer, so i need to change my port to COM (n) instead of just writing the port number for the mac.

Many Thanks,
Joshua Lay